# 0 energy one way valves

Tags: valves

Is there such thing as a check valve that takes no energy from water for water to pass through? What is the name of this/these check valve type/s? I barely know anything about engineering, just have this question.

Comment: What do you mean by zero energy?

Comment: I assume he means zero energy loss compared to an equivalent length of straight pipe?

Answer (score 1):

No, there will be losses, such as pushing a flap or a disc against a spring or even just against the mass of the flap as well as friction losses due to shape changes of the duct.

The real question is will these losses be significant compared to the rest of the system, if they are needed and the design or choice of the oneway valve is appropriate then there is little or no issue. However if you use a strong spring loaded valve in a system that cannot overcome the spring force then it won't work.